# serialport1 does not exist in context

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication21
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            label1.Text = " OCCUPIED";
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
          this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DoUpdate));
        }

        private void DoUpdate(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            string InputString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            string[] data = InputString.Split(',');

            textBox1.Text = data[0];
            textBox2.Text = data[1];

           int b;
           int d;

           bool result = Int32.TryParse(data[0], out b);
           bool sonuc = Int32.TryParse(data[1], out d);
           if (result)
           {
               if (b < 224)
               {
                   button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                   label1.Text = " OCCUPIED";
               }
               else
               {
                   button1.BackColor = Color.Lime;
                   label1.Text = "AVAILABLE";
               }
           }

           if (sonuc)
           {
               if (d< 224)
               {
                   button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                   label1.Text = " OCCUPIED";
               }
               else
               {
                   button1.BackColor = Color.Lime;
                   label1.Text = "AVAILABLE";
               }
           }

        int b = Int16.Parse(a);
        textBox1.Text= a.ToString();*/

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Visible = true;
            listBox1.Items.Add("Değerler alınıyor!");

            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = "COM11";
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            listBox1.Items.Add("Durduruldu!");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error:

> "serialport1 does not exist in context"

What can l do? Whenever I want to compile I get the above mention error.
Do I have to add any library?
I am using visual Studio 2010

Comment: Where is the code where you set the value of `serialport1`? Look at the example in the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: (Supposedly) At the end of `DoUpdate()` you have a closing block quote (`*/`) and are missing a right curly bracket (`}`). And the two last lines of `DoUpdate()` (`int b = ...`) should probably be commented out or deleted? Have you added `serialPort1` in the designer? Maybe renamed it to something else?

Comment: Thank you it worked